# Code only works when unused array is left in

Tags: c

I have an array `int ofd[4]` that I am no longer using in my code. However, if I comment it out, my code no longer works - I get no output on stdout and the file is created, but empty.

To observe this behavior, compile and run the code as `./manatee /bin/ls -l /usr/bin/sort -r out.txt`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define READ_STDIN    0
#define READ_STDOUT   1
#define WRITE_STDIN   2
#define WRITE_STDOUT  3
#define NUM_PIPES     4

int pipes[NUM_PIPES][2];

#define READ_FD  0
#define WRITE_FD 1

void closeThePipes() {
    close(pipes[READ_STDIN][READ_FD]);
    close(pipes[READ_STDOUT][WRITE_FD]);
    close(pipes[READ_STDOUT][READ_FD]);
    close(pipes[READ_STDIN][WRITE_FD]);
    close(pipes[WRITE_STDIN][READ_FD]);
    close(pipes[WRITE_STDOUT][WRITE_FD]);
    close(pipes[WRITE_STDOUT][READ_FD]);
    close(pipes[WRITE_STDIN][WRITE_FD]);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    if (argc != 6) {
        exit(1);
    }

    pipe(pipes[READ_STDOUT]);
    pipe(pipes[READ_STDIN]);
    pipe(pipes[WRITE_STDOUT]);
    pipe(pipes[WRITE_STDIN]);

    int ofd[4];

    if (!fork()) {
        dup2(pipes[READ_STDIN][READ_FD], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(pipes[READ_STDOUT][WRITE_FD], STDOUT_FILENO);
        closeThePipes();

        char * args[2];
        args[0] = argv[1];
        args[1] = argv[2];
        execv(args[0], &args);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else {
        if (!fork()) {
            dup2(pipes[WRITE_STDIN][READ_FD], STDIN_FILENO);
            dup2(pipes[WRITE_STDOUT][WRITE_FD], STDOUT_FILENO);
            closeThePipes();

            char * args[2];
            args[0] = argv[3];
            args[1] = argv[4];
            execv(args[0], &args);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        } else {
            char buffer[100];
            int count;

            close(pipes[READ_STDIN][READ_FD]);
            close(pipes[READ_STDOUT][WRITE_FD]);
            close(pipes[WRITE_STDIN][READ_FD]);
            close(pipes[WRITE_STDOUT][WRITE_FD]);

            FILE * tee = fopen(argv[5], "w");

            close(pipes[READ_STDIN][WRITE_FD]);
            while ((count = read(pipes[READ_STDOUT][READ_FD], buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1)) > 0) {
                if (count > 0) {
                    buffer[count] = '\0';
                    fprintf(tee, "%s", buffer);
                    write(pipes[WRITE_STDIN][WRITE_FD], buffer, count);
                }
            }
            close(pipes[READ_STDOUT][READ_FD]);
            close(pipes[WRITE_STDIN][WRITE_FD]);
            while ((count = read(pipes[WRITE_STDOUT][READ_FD], buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1)) > 0) {
                if (count > 0) {
                    buffer[count] = '\0';
                    printf("%s", buffer);
                }
            }
            close(pipes[WRITE_STDIN][READ_FD]);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer works"?  Specifics are critically important.

Comment: @AndrewHenle edited with more details

Comment: When you get strange behaviour like this it almost always means you have a bug causing Undefined Behaviour in your program. For example, execv(args[0], &args); is not correct and has UB. From the execv man page: "The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer". Looks like none of your `args` arrays are NULL pointer terminated. There may be other UB bugs (I haven't looked). Fix the above first and re-test.

Comment: @kaylum That did it - my code now works without that array. Would you mind making an answer?

Comment: Compiling with *warnings enabled*, e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` will point out areas of your code you need to address -- before you even attempt to run it. You will have similar warning levels regardless of your compiler -- check your available options and always use them. e.g. `warning: passing argument 2 of ‘execv’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] execv(args[0], &args);`

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99`) )  Then fix those warnings.   With so many 'serious' warnings, it is a wonder the code works at all.  For instance, this line: `execv(args[0], &args);` has an invalid second parameter, It should be: `execv(args[0], args);` and the variable `ofd` is not used.  (and there are some implicit conversions that you probably should fix.

Comment: when exiting because the incorrect number of command line parameters was used, the call to `exit()` will not tell the user what is wrong.  suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE" %s <parm1> <parm2> <parm3> <parm4> <parm5> <parm6>\n", argv[0] );`  just before calling `exit()`

Comment: when calling `pipe()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `fork()` there are three possible conditions to check for: 1) <0 means an error occurred,  2) ==0 means in the child process and fork() successful. 3) greater than 0 means in the parent process and fork() successful.  If/When the call to `fork()` fails (which it can do) then the code goes downhill in a hurry.

Comment: the `while((count =` statement already checks that the `count` is greater than 0, so no need to check it again with: `if (count > 0)`.  Two places in the code have this problem.

Comment: when calling `fopen()` always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the code that adjusts the `args` array contents does not move all the pointers, so the original content becomes modified to: argv[1], argv[2], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4], argv[5], NULL   So, even when the other problems (as noted in my prior comments are fixed), an invalid args[] array is being passed via `execv()`   There are two places in the code with this problem.   Suggest generating a whole new array from the desired entries in the original args[] for each call to `execv()`

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for all your suggestions! This code is nowhere near finished - I was only stuck on that one problem before going through to clean it up. Your help is definitely appreciated :)

Comment: OT: `read()` returns `ssize_t`, so `count` should better be of type  `int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you get strange behaviour like this it almost always means you have a bug causing Undefined Behaviour in your program. For example, `execv(args[0], &args);` is not correct and has UB. From the [`execv` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv):

> The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer

In your case, each of the `args` arrays are not correctly terminated with a NULL pointer entry. So just need to change those parts of the code as follows:

```
char * args[3];  // Increased this array size by one element
args[0] = argv[3];
args[1] = argv[4];
args[2] = NULL;  // Terminate with a NULL entry
execv(args[0], args); // Pass args instead of &args for type correctness
```

Comment: Shouldn't this `...  &args);` better just be `... , args);`?  `execv(args[0], &args);` would cause a compiler warning because of passing the wrong type, I suspect. (Also see this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400923/code-only-works-when-unused-array-is-left-in#comment58505117_35400923 on this)

Comment: @alk Yes you are right. I didn't look carefully at that. Corrected now. Thanks!